# Docker Compose contains unsupported option: 'environment'

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, yaml, containers

**The following is my docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: "3"
services:
    coreapi:
        build:
            context: ./theapi
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    sqlserver:
        build:
            context: ./sqlserver
            environment: 
                ACCEPT_EULA="Y"
                SA_PASSWORD="Pwd12345!"
        ports:
            - "11433:1433"
```

**ERROR:**

> ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   services.sqlserver.build contains unsupported option: 'environment'

I have tried using online formatter, I have tried removing double quotes, adding single quotes. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you're using `=` in the environment lines they need a `-` prefix, e.g.: `- ACCEPT_EULA=Y`

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out. I did not use hyphen because I saw several examples without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must make the environment as a list outside the `build` :

```
sqlserver:
 environment: 
        - ACCEPT_EULA="Y"
        - SA_PASSWORD="Pwd12345!"
```

if you want to use it inside the `build` directive you need to use `args` not `environment`

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be correct. But where do I read about it? Everything there is to know about docker-compose yaml

Comment: see here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to add hyphen:

```
version: "3"
services:
    coreapi:
        build:
            context: ./theapi
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    sqlserver:
        build:
            context: ./sqlserver
        environment: 
            - ACCEPT_EULA="Y"
            - SA_PASSWORD="Pwd12345!"
        ports:
            - "11433:1433"
```